# Calculations beetween two columns with two conditions and id range

Tags: r

I want to know the price movement in pips from the begining of the trend to the end using some data.
I have a solution with some strings of code, but I hope that there is an easier way to do it. Could you, please help me to find it.

Example data:

```r
Ent_Lvl <- c(66437, 66533, 66533, 66574, 66602, 66709, 66732, 66685, 66608, 66608, 66586, 66631, 66685, 66724, 66812, 66866)  
Tr_Ch <- c(66357, 66453, 66453, 66494, 66522, 66628, 66651, 66765, 66688, 66688, 66666, 66551, 66605, 66643, 66731, 66786)  
Tr <- c(rep(1,7), rep(2,4), rep(1,5))  
id2 <-c(rep(15,7), rep(16,4), rep(17,5))  
x <- data.frame(Ent_Lvl, Tr, Tr_Ch, id2)
```

It looks like this:

```r
> x
   Ent_Lvl Tr Tr_Ch id2
1    66276  1 66196  14
2    66437  1 66357  15
3    66533  1 66453  15
4    66533  1 66453  15
5    66574  1 66494  15
6    66602  1 66522  15
7    66709  1 66628  15
8    66732  1 66651  15
9    66685  2 66765  16
10   66608  2 66688  16
11   66608  2 66688  16
12   66586  2 66666  16
13   66631  1 66551  17
14   66685  1 66605  17
15   66724  1 66643  17
16   66812  1 66731  17
17   66866  1 66786  17
```

### Step 1

```r
library(dplyr)
y <- x%>% 
group_by(id2, Tr) %>% # group by ranges
summarise(Ent_Lvl2_max = max(Ent_Lvl), # find max value from Ent_Lvl column for Tr = 2
    Tr_Ch2_min = min(Tr_Ch),           # find min value from Tr_Ch column for Tr = 2
    Ent_Lvl1_min = min(Ent_Lvl),       # find min value from Ent_Lvl column for Tr = 1
    Tr_Ch1_max = max(Tr_Ch)) %>%       # find max value from Tr_Ch column for Tr = 1
mutate(ChTrLvl2 = Ent_Lvl2_max - Tr_Ch2_min,
    ChTrLvl1 = Tr_Ch1_max - Ent_Lvl1_min) # add two new columns for the next calculations
```

The result after step 1:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   id2 [3]
    id2    Tr Ent_Lvl2_max Tr_Ch2_min Ent_Lvl1_min Tr_Ch1_max ChTrLvl2 ChTrLvl1
  <int> <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1    15     1        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
2    16     2        66685      66666        66586      66765       19      179
3    17     1        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
```

### Step 2

```r
x <- x%>% left_join(y, by = c("id2", "Tr")) #join new data frame y from Step 1 to x data frame
```

The result after step 2:

```r
> x
   Ent_Lvl Tr id2 Tr_Ch Ent_Lvl2_max Tr_Ch2_min Ent_Lvl1_min Tr_Ch1_max ChTrLvl2 ChTrLvl1
1    66437  1  15 66357        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
2    66533  1  15 66453        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
3    66533  1  15 66453        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
4    66574  1  15 66494        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
5    66602  1  15 66522        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
6    66709  1  15 66628        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
7    66732  1  15 66651        66732      66357        66437      66651      375      214
8    66685  2  16 66765        66685      66666        66586      66765       19      179
9    66608  2  16 66688        66685      66666        66586      66765       19      179
10   66608  2  16 66688        66685      66666        66586      66765       19      179
11   66586  2  16 66666        66685      66666        66586      66765       19      179
12   66631  1  17 66551        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
13   66685  1  17 66605        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
14   66724  1  17 66643        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
15   66812  1  17 66731        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
16   66866  1  17 66786        66866      66551        66631      66786      315      155
```

### Step 3

```r
x$DeltaTr <- ifelse(x$Tr==1, x$ChTrLvl1, x$ChTrLvl2) # add desired column with condition to x data frame
```

The final result is:

```r
> x %>% select(Tr, id2, DeltaTr)
   Tr id2 DeltaTr
1   1  15     214
2   1  15     214
3   1  15     214
4   1  15     214
5   1  15     214
6   1  15     214
7   1  15     214
8   2  16      19
9   2  16      19
10  2  16      19
11  2  16      19
12  1  17     155
13  1  17     155
14  1  17     155
15  1  17     155
16  1  17     155
```

I'm expect to find the earsiest way of solving this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar, just consolidating steps:

```
x %>%
  group_by(id2, Tr) %>%
  mutate(DeltaTr = if_else(Tr == 1,
                           max(Tr_Ch) - min(Ent_Lvl),
                           max(Ent_Lvl) - min(Tr_Ch))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 5
   Ent_Lvl    Tr Tr_Ch   id2 DeltaTr
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1   66437     1 66357    15     214
 2   66533     1 66453    15     214
 3   66533     1 66453    15     214
 4   66574     1 66494    15     214
 5   66602     1 66522    15     214
 6   66709     1 66628    15     214
 7   66732     1 66651    15     214
 8   66685     2 66765    16      19
 9   66608     2 66688    16      19
10   66608     2 66688    16      19
11   66586     2 66666    16      19
12   66631     1 66551    17     155
13   66685     1 66605    17     155
14   66724     1 66643    17     155
15   66812     1 66731    17     155
16   66866     1 66786    17     155
```

Comment: Great! It's work. Thank you so much for this elegant solution!